# How to handle requests that will be picked up by a person and responded to within 5 minutes

Tags: usability, interaction-design, notification, feedback, activity-feed

I'm currently designing a voucher/discount journey.
Due to system constraints, this is the scenario
User needs to request a voucher.
The request then goes to a crm that is managed by individuals.
Individuals will respond with voucher number within 5 minutes of the request coming into the CRM.
Once the voucher/discount is sent to the user, they only have 2 minutes within which to use it on the platform. If they don't it will expire and they need to request another voucher/discount.
I've thought of in-app notifications to let the user know that the voucher is ready, but since the voucher is only valid for 2 minutes, I'm not sure if there's a better way?

Comment: Can you clarify why you’re looking for a better way? What’s the problem with the current approach? Do you have screenshots/mockups etc. to share?

Comment: @jazZRo I can't share the details but a qualifying customer will receive an offer of being able to apply for a discounted voucher. Once they apply for the voucher, they will receive a response (discount due to the voucher) within anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minutes.
Thereafter the customer needs to make payment for the goods within 2 minutes or else the voucher/discount expires

Answer (score 0):

To handle requests for vouchers that need a quick response within 5 minutes and have a short validity period of 2 minutes, You can use notifications, displaying timers, and some other ways:

- Real-time Notifications: Send in-app notifications to inform users
  that their voucher request has been processed and the voucher number
  is available. Ensure the notifications are delivered instantly to
  minimize delays.
- Push Notifications: Use push notifications, if possible, to deliver
  immediate alerts to the user's device, ensuring they are promptly
  notified about the voucher availability.
- Countdown Timer: Display a visible countdown timer within the app,
  showing the remaining time for voucher utilization. This creates
  urgency for users to act quickly.
- Simple Voucher Redemption: Enable users to redeem their vouchers with
  a single click or tap, minimizing steps and simplifying the
  redemption process.
- Support Channel: Provide clear instructions for requesting a new
  voucher if the previous one expires. Offer a support channel for
  quick assistance if needed.

By implementing these strategies, users will be promptly notified about their vouchers, reminded of the expiration timeframe, and able to quickly redeem them within the given validity period.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Ali but chatGPT gave me these exact answeres already. Hopefully someone has encountered a similar scenario previously or can point me to something they have seen in the past

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a socket server, and connect it with an interface on the receiver's end (the responder) who then is getting some kind of notification through that interface.

That could be push notifications or simply redirect to a page where the information is present for the responder to accept the request.

You could also send an SMS with the above, so the chances for seeing the request is higher :)